# Slow django model instance creation with Docker

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

I have django application with some model. I have `manage.py` command that creates `n` models and saves it to db. It runs with decent speed on my host machine.

But if I run it in docker it runs very slow, 1 instance created and saved in 40-50 seconds. I think I am missing something on how Docker works, can somebody point out why performance is low and what can i do with it?

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    restart: always
    image: "postgres:9.6"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - /usr/local/var/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=my_db
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres

  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "./wait-for-it.sh db:5432 --timeout=15; python manage.py migrate; python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000; python manage.py mock 5"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    expose:
      - "8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

**dockerfile for web service**:

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1
ADD . .
WORKDIR .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN chmod +x wait-for-it.sh
```

Comment: Are you doing this on a server/VM? Tried to do it on the same machine without docker?

Comment: @lorenzvth7 Doing this on local machine (mac) with maxed computing resources. Doing this without docker is way faster.

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is most likely the volume `/usr/local/var/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql` as you are using it on Mac. As I understand the Docker for Mac solution, it uses file sharing to implement host volumes, which is a lot slower then native filesystem access.

A possible workaround is to use a docker volume instead of a host volume. Here is an example:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  postgres_data:

services:
  db:
    restart: always
    image: "postgres:9.6"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=my_db
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres

  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "./wait-for-it.sh db:5432 --timeout=15; python manage.py migrate; python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000; python manage.py mock 5"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    expose:
      - "8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Please note that this may complicate management of the postgres data, as you can't simply access the data from your Mac. You can only use the docker CLI or containers to access, modify and backup this data. Also, I'm not sure what happens if you uninstall Docker from your Mac, it may be that you lose this data.

Comment: You don't lose data if you uninstall docker. I have a volumen set for postgres+django and works perfect

Answer (score 1):

Two things, can be a probable cause:

1. Starting of docker container takes some time, so if you start new container for each instance this can add up.
2. What storage driver do you use? Docker (often) defaults to device mapper loopback storage driver, which is **slow**. Here is [some context](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/06/notes-on-fedora-centos-and-docker-storage-drivers/). This will be painfull especially if you start this container often.

Other than that your config looks sensibly, and there are no obvious causes problems there. So if the above two points don't apply to you, please add some extra comments --- like how you actually *add these model instances*.